# Word for when a subclass label would be a valid label for a parent class

Tags: vocabulary

Words like "book" cover a class of object, whilst "textbook" covers a subclass encapsulated by "book". That said, a literal interpretation of "textbook" suggests that it would be a valid label for the parent class. The prepending of "text" seems to narrow the scope of meaning without narrowing the literal meaning of the string.

Is there a name for this phenomenon? I.e. when a subclass label would be a valid label for the parent class.

Comment: If someone else can phrase this question more clearly, please do!

Comment: This question makes me think of [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu). I guess a similar example would be "Siamese cat" as a subset of the "cat" class? But "textbooks" are a subset of all "books": not all books contain text (picture books exist), and textbook is distinct from story book (or fiction). It is not accurate to label all books as textbooks. But you can say all textbooks are books.